# How can I typeset cross-method factorization tables?

Tags: tables, math-mode, diagrams

I would like something akin to this:

[image: A cross-method factorization "chart"]

I have tried tabular but I couldn't get the red lines (crosses). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

$ \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}\begin{array}{l!{\hskip0.8em}ll>{\columncolor{Tan}}l }
m\pnode[0.4ex, 0.5ex]{a} & \pnode[-0.4ex, 0.5ex]{b}-n & -2n & -3n \\
m\pnode[0.45ex, 0.5ex]{c}& \pnode[-0.4ex, 0.5ex]{d}-12n & -6n & -4n \\
\hline
& -mn-12mn & -2mn-6mn & -3mn-4mn \\
&=-13mn & =-8mn & =-7mn
\psset{linecolor=Coral, linewidth=0.5pt}\ncline{a}{d}\ncline{b}{c}
\end{array} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a MWE with TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
                >{$}l<{\quad $} % Controls the gap size
                @{}
                *{2}{>{$}l<{$}}
                >{\columncolor{Tan}$}l<{$}
               }
\tikzmarknode{A}{m} & \tikzmarknode{B}{-n}      & -2n       & -3n \\ % TikZ nodes are defined as A, B, C and D.
\tikzmarknode{C}{m} & \tikzmarknode{D}{-12n}    & -6n       & -4n \\
\hline
                    & -mn-12mn                  & -2mn-6mn  & -3mn-4mn \\
                    &=-13mn                     & =-8mn     & =-7mn
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[Coral,-{Stealth[length=1mm]}] (A.east) -- (D.west); % Lines are drawn with arrow size. You can use ([yshift=<amount>pt,xshift=<amount>pt]A.east) to shift the positions of the lines relative to the anchor points.
\draw[Coral,-{Stealth[length=1mm]}] (C.east) -- (B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used @campa MWE as a template.

Comment: The arrows are misplaced.

Comment: @projetmbc Read the comments. :) If you follow the diagram, I believe that is the correct direction of the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

With `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$ \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{NiceArray}{l!{\quad}ll>{\columncolor{red!15}}l}[colortbl-like]
m & -n & -2n & -3n \\
m& -12n & -6n & -4n \\
\hline
& -mn-12mn & -2mn-6mn & -3mn-4mn \\
&=-13mn & =-8mn & =-7mn
\CodeAfter \tikz \draw [red] (1-1.east) -- (2-2.west) 
                             (1-2.west) -- (2-1.east) ;
\end{NiceArray} $

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` use PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]